# Is it possible to read ArcGIS CSVLayer Source from an object rather than a file like .csv or .geojson?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Is it possible to read ArcGIS CSVLayer Source from an object rather than a file like .csv or .geojson?

I have data in my database about an object including Latitude, Longitude and Altitude. When I want to display these objects onto the map, now I should be creating a CSV file or a GeoJson file.

Is there any way that I could provide these data to the CSVLayer without creating these files but reading directly from an Object(**JavaScript Array or Object**)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is serialize your JavaScript Array into a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object and pass it's [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to [`CSVLayer.url`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-CSVLayer.html#url).

```
var csvContent = [
  "time,latitude,longitude,depth,mag",
  "2019-06-28T11:17:31.734Z,8.4069,-82.8409,22.89,4.4",
  "2019-06-28T09:24:08.880Z,37.5128326,-118.7975006,6.01,2.8",
  "2019-06-28T08:30:42.866Z,-29.3884,-70.916,81.42,5"
].join("\n");

const blob = new Blob([csvContent], {type: "text/csv"});
const url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var csvLayer = new CSVLayer({ url });
```

See the following CodePen that uses above technique to show [USGS](https://www.usgs.gov/products/data-and-tools/real-time-data/earthquakes) earthquake data: https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/0ebf1e5fd85f36c09b6d87e15b7956b1

Comment: Is there a way that I could directly provide the source from SQL Server DataBase